# Apply and append data frame in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, dplyr, bind

I am trying to convert lets say dataframe ALPHA:

```
     A    B    C     D      E
1 0.80 2.00 0.09 201.1 335.00
```

to  dataframe BETA

```
     A    B    C     D      E   A1   B1   C1    D1     E1  
1 0.80 2.00 0.09 201.1 335.00 1.60 3.00 0.18 402.2 670.00
```

so pretty much multiplies by 2 and appends.

Currently doing it as:

```
  curveCalculator <- function(variable, variableName){
       // Need variableName here for another part
       return(variable*2)
  }


  BETA <- lapply(ALPHA, function(variableName, variable){
    calculated <- curveCalculator(variable, variableName)
    return(calculated)
  }, names(optional))

  bind_cols(ALPHA, as.data.frame(BETA,col.names=paste(names(BETA), 1, sep="")))
```

However, it passes curveCalculator ALL NAMES, so for A it would pass 0.80 for variable and c("A","B","C","D","E") for variable name. I want it to only pass "A" for A, "B" for B and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(purrr)
BETA <- map2(ALPHA, names(ALPHA), curveCalculator) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
names(BETA) <- paste0(names(BETA), 1)
cbind(ALPHA, BETA)
```

Comment: I need a way to pass the current column's name to the funs function